# Is there a name for a pattern used in EF Core internals?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I wanted to understand how extensions like `EF.Functions.Like` are implemented under the hood of EF Core, but when I navigated to the implementation of it, I saw it does nothing except for throwing an `InvalidOperationException`

```
public static bool Like(this DbFunctions _, string? matchExpression, string? pattern)
    => throw new InvalidOperationException(CoreStrings.FunctionOnClient(nameof(Like)));
```

It took me some time to understand that this extension is used only when EF translates it into SQL - it scans `Expression` and if there is a call to extension, then it should be replaced with specific SQL function. For some reason, it was not that obvious as with primitive comparison types. And I am now curious, is there a name for this construction or pattern?

It reminds me of marker interfaces, that serve single purpose, for example, during assembly scanning.

Could this be "marker extension"? Or "Expression-only extension"? Or noone even bothers naming it because of the limited use (only in expressions).

Comment: Like translation registered [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/Internal/LikeTranslator.cs), there is no special attributes or something like that.

Comment: Don't think this has a name.  LINQ uses expressions to write SQL.  The expressions need not to be evaluated.  There is an actual difference that most C# developers don't know:  Writing `x => x.Id` is not a function.  It is an expression.  Devs don't notice because when we write stuff like that for function purposes, the compiler compiles the Expression into a lambda function.  Most devs just don't know the difference.

Comment: [User-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) - here you can get some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario described, where a method is defined in C# but is intended to be replaced by specific SQL functionality when executed as part of a LINQ query against an Entity Framework Core (EF Core) context, it is part of a pattern often referred to as the "method translation pattern" within the context of ORMs (Object Relational Mappers) like EF Core.

The idea is that certain methods are defined in C# code to be used within LINQ queries, but they aren't meant to be executed in C#. Instead, they act as markers that the ORM's query translator will recognize and replace with corresponding SQL operations during the translation of the LINQ expression tree into a SQL command.

In EF Core specifically, this pattern is facilitated by a component known as the "method call translator" which is responsible for recognizing these special methods and knowing how to translate them into SQL. The terms "marker method" or "translatable method" might also be used to describe individual methods like `EF.Functions.Like` that are part of this pattern.

So in a broader context, this could be considered a specific use-case of the method translation pattern in ORM systems, and in EF Core, the mechanism enabling this pattern is the method call translator component.